# Hide / show div toggle

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have the following mark up with a basic and advanced search divs.

```
<div class="form">
     <form>
         <input type="text" name="first_name">
         <input type="text" name="last_name">

       <div id="Basic" class="slide">
         <input type="text" name="location"> 
       </div>

       <a onclick="ShowDiv('Adv');">+ show advanced fields</a>

      <div id="Adv" class="slide hidden">
         <input type="text" name="first_name2">
         <input type="text" name="last_name2">
         <input type="text" name="street">
         <input type="text" name="town">
         <input type="text" name="country">
       </div>
     </form>

     <a onclick="ShowDiv('Basic');">- hide advanced fields</a> 
    </div>
```

The toggle is achieved with the following script

```
 function HideDiv() {
         $('.slide').hide();
     }
     function ShowDiv(ctrl) {
         HideDiv();
         $('#' + ctrl).show();
     }
     ShowDiv('Basic');
```

I also have trhe following JQuery in place that shows the adv div if a user returns to the page from a results page assuming he completed any input fields from the search form initially

```
//show adv div based on input value data 
$(function(){
    if($("#Adv input[value!='']").length)
        $('#Adv').show(); // if this is the element you want to show.
 });
```

I need to eliminate the need of using both links. I need to have only one link depending on state. So if the div basic is shown as default the link will say show advanced. When the advanced is shown the anchor link should switch to hide advanced

How do I need to edit my jQuery and mark up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $(".toggler").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find("span").toggle();
        $(".togglee").slideToggle();
    });

    //show adv div based on input value data 
    if($("#Adv input[value!='']").length) {
        $('.toggler').click(); // if this is the element you want to show.
    }

});
```

And the HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="form">
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="first_name">
                <input type="text" name="last_name">

                <div class="Basic togglee" class="slide">
                    <input type="text" name="location">
                </div>

                <div id="Adv" class="slide hidden togglee">
                    <input type="text" name="first_name2">
                    <input type="text" name="last_name2">
                    <input type="text" name="street">
                    <input type="text" name="town">
                    <input type="text" name="country">
                </div>
            </form>

            <a class="toggle-link toggler">
                <span>+ show advanced fields</span>
                <span class="hidden">- hide advanced fields</span>
            </a>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2sqnc/2/).

Comment: I like this. But it doesn't expand in IE9

Comment: Weird, no rocket science here. Any error messages? I only have IE8 so can't check.

Comment: Well, it works but if I return back to the search form page from a results page and my advanved div is open (based on the user has used the advanced search input fileds) the link still shows show advanced even thought the div is already open and then the whole thing is messed up

Comment: I have added the extra jQuery in place in my code so you can see that complicated things now. I like your solution and it works fine. But what do we need to add to it so it can regognise that if the div is open at the time of page load, then the link should show appropriately?

Comment: Well, this is not exactly what I intended. As I said, I need to have that code in place ( $('#Adv').show(); ) so there is the if statement whereas a user completed any of the advanced input fields then the div should show. At the moment the div shows always hidden and that's not what I need.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2sqnc/3/ <-- this works. Maybe the input is empty on page load? You need to populate it somehow, probably from server-side.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<a class="toggle-link" href="#Adv" >toggle advanced fields</a>
```

js

```
$('.toggle-link').on('click.toggle', function(evt) {
   var tgt = $($(this).attr('href'));  /* tgt = $("#Adv") */
   evt.preventDefault();

   if (tgt.length) { /* if $("#Adv") exists */
      $(this).toggleClass(".expanded"); /* add or remove this class for the link */
      tgt.toggleClass(".hidden"); /* add or remove this class in the target element */
   }
});
```

css

```
.toggle-link:before { content: "+"; padding-right: 1em; }
.toggle-link.expanded:before { content: "-"; }
```

in this example, the information about the element to hide/show is passed along with `href` attribute, and the event handler is not inline, so you can avoid to call the same function multiple times mixing javascript and markup together.

See example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SnKHg/

Comment: That what pretty much what I am looking for. I like it but doesn't toggle at the moment

Comment: No idea why it is not working on my page. Trying to see any existing scripts that might be a conflict. I really like your solution

Comment: look at your javascript console both when you load the page and when you clicked over the link. Otherwise check if the function is actually called (using some `console.log()`) and if the element, you're trying to toggle exists

Answer (score 0):

This function can made better ofcourse, but it is one way to do this.

Make a link `<a href="#" class="show adv">Click</a>`.

The jQuery function toggles the class, thus the functionality.

```
$('a.show').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass('basic'))
    {
        ('#adv').hide();
        ('#basic').show();
        $(this).addClass('adv');
        $(this).removeClass('basic');
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('adv'))
    {
        ('#basic').hide();
        ('#adv').show();
        $(this).addClass('basic');
        $(this).removeClass('adv');
    }           
});
```

But a jQuery UI accordeon is better for this, especially when you have more containers that you want to show/hide.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

js

```
$("a.toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div.form').find("#Adv").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("hide");
    if ($(this).hasClass("hide")) {
        $(this).text("hide advanced fields");
    } else {
        $(this).text("show advanced fields");
    }


});
```

html

```
<div class="form">
 <form>
     <input type="text" name="first_name">
     <input type="text" name="last_name">

   <div class="Basic" class="slide">
     <input type="text" name="location">
   </div>

  <div id="Adv" class="slide hidden">
     <input type="text" name="first_name2">
     <input type="text" name="last_name2">
     <input type="text" name="street">
     <input type="text" name="town">
     <input type="text" name="country" value="gh">
   </div>
 </form>

 <a class='toggle'>show advanced fields</a>
</div>
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/c27dW/

Answer (score 0):

Find below.

```
<div class="form">
     <form>
         <input type="text" name="first_name">
         <input type="text" name="last_name">

       <div class="Basic" class="slide">
         <input type="text" name="location"> 
       </div>

       <a class="toggle-link" onclick="ShowHideDiv();" id='bttn'>+ show advanced fields</a>

      <div id="Adv" class="slide hidden">
         <input type="text" name="first_name2">
         <input type="text" name="last_name2">
         <input type="text" name="street">
         <input type="text" name="town">
         <input type="text" name="country">
       </div>
     </form>


    </div>
```

I've modified the javascript part as well.

```
  function Hide() {
             $('.slide').hide();
         }

    function Show() {

      $('.slide').show();
    }
         function ShowHideDiv() {

           var str = $("#bttn").text();
           if(str === '+ show advanced fields'){

             $("#bttn").text('- hide advanced fields');
             Show();

           }
           else {
              $("#bttn").text('+ show advanced fields');
             Hide();

           }

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to other answer, may be if u want some animation then u should have look at this http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggle/#option-options